# Properly using of the <T> type in generic methods in C#

Tags: c#, generics

So my real method is a lot different but I come down to this. It seems I don't fully understand how to handle the generic `<T>` type when I'm working with generic methods. My understanding is that we use generic methods when we want the same logic to work for different types, but we want the freedom to determine the exact type at run time. So it seems pretty natural to me that when I have a method like this :

```
internal static void ChangeCode<T>(Entity entity) where T : Entity
{

    T tempEntity;

    if (entity.GetType() == typeof(SomeMoreSpecificEntity))
    {
      tempEntity = new SomeMoreSpecificEntity();
    }
}
```

However if I try something like this I get an error `Can not convert type T to SomeMoreSpecificEntity`.

So where am I wrong. Isn't the idea to be able to do exactly this - declare a common type in compile time and cast to more specific type in run time?

Comment: I thought that the general rule of thumb was: "if you need to know the exact type, it's not generic"...

Comment: @Trustme-I'maDoctor Arguably true, but doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @Jonners That's why it's only a comment... :)

Comment: @Trustme-I'maDoctor Yep, and I upvoted it for its' validity. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the code you're trying to write is broken. For example, suppose I called:

```
ChangeCode<BananaEntity>(new SomeMoreSpecificEntity());
```

That would try to assign a reference of type `SomeMoreSpecificEntity` to a variable of type `T`, where `T` is `BananaEntity`.

It's not clear what you're trying to achieve, but that's why your current code won't compile. Given that you're not actually *using* `T` other than for a purpose for which it won't work your current code could be changed to make it a *non-generic* method, and just declare `tempEntity` as type `Entity`. Of course, that might not work for what you really want to do, but as you've only provided the non-working code, that's hard to determine :(

Three points about this line:

```
if (entity.GetType() == typeof(SomeMoreSpecificEntity))
```

- Did you actually mean `entity` to be of type `T` rather than type `Entity`? Currently it can be *any* entity
- Did you really want to check the *exact* type? Normally you'd use `is` instead of calling `GetType` and comparing it directly with a type
- Normally comparing types like this is a sign that you should consider a redesign. It's definitely not *generic* at this point, as it only copes with types that are hard-coded in it.

Comment: Yes, you are right at all this points. I hardly misunderstand the use of generics. It's only `Entity` type that I'm going to use.

Answer (score 4):

You can't do that. Check following situation:

You have another class named `SomeMoreSpecificEntity2` which is declared:

```
class SomeMoreSpecificEntity2 : Entity
{
}
```

You call your method `ChangeCode<SomeMoreSpecificEntity2>`, so `T` is `SomeMoreSpecificEntity2`, so `tempEntity` is `SomeMoreSpecificEntity2` as well, but you're trying to assign `SomeMoreSpecificEntity` to it. That can't work.

You can try changing it to :

```
internal static void ChangeCode<T>(Entity entity) where T : Entity
{
    Entity tempEntity;

    if (entity.GetType() == typeof(SomeMoreSpecificEntity))
    {
        tempEntity = new SomeMoreSpecificEntity();
    }
}
```

It compiles.

Comment: The first part shows why it cannot be done. The second one shows what can be done to avoid it, but in my opinion it just does not make sense :)

Comment: Hmm, yes this works but I guess in fact if I know I'm going to work only with classes that derive from `Entity` I don't need to use generic method in first place. Is that so?

Answer (score -3):

```
tempEntity = (T)(object)new SomeMoreSpecificEntity();
```

T can only cast with object